# Remove Cancel Button background tint in Search Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using XCode 8.2.1 to develop an iOS App. If you look carefully at the Cancel button in the image below, you can see that it has a light shade of blue as the background. I've been trying to remove this background from the Cancel button with no luck so far:

[image: Cancel button tint background]

I realized it is a low opacity shade of whatever color I give as the "Tint". If I set the tint to "Clear color", this annoying background is gone, but the "Cancel" text also gets disappeared.

[image: Tint selection Xcode]

How can I remove this background from the cancel button?

Comment: share your code ? please

Comment: This is not related to the code I have in Swift right? Its all in the storyboard. Although in the code I have logic to hide and show the cancel button only when required (when the search input is active)

Comment: i think this type of problem can be solved if  you doing pragmatically  most of time  storyboard failed to play with color .

Comment: change your background to Default Position

Comment: @HarshalValanda I can see only "Default" in the dropdown there.. what did you mean by "Default Position"?

Comment: Not color you have background and search text field set there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is facing this problem, this is how I solved it:

[image]

I removed this scope title and the tint was gone. I don't know how it got there in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the cancel button using following code

```
searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
```